# Pull customer data into all columns in a csv file

Tags: php, csv

This is my current code which pulls all data into a single column. I would like it 
to pull data into its own column. Thanks for any help

```
<?php
include('codelibrary/inc/variables.php');
include("session.php");
$obj= new database_class();

$query = $obj->getAnyTableAllData($obj->getTable("var_customer")," and email != '' order by email ");
$filename = 'customer_email.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');

foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    $_csv_data= $v["email"]. "\n";
    fwrite( $fp, $_csv_data );
}


foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    $_csv_data= $v["first_name"]. "\n";
    fwrite( $fp, $_csv_data );
}


foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    $_csv_data= $v["business"]. "\n";
    fwrite( $fp, $_csv_data );
}


foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    $_csv_data= $v["phone_no"]. "\n";
    fwrite( $fp, $_csv_data );
}


foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    $_csv_data= $v["shipping_address"]. "\n";
    fwrite( $fp, $_csv_data );
}

fclose($fp);

if(is_file($filename))
{
    $size=filesize("$filename");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
 }
else
{
    echo "Invalid file!";
}
?>
```

This is my first post on here and I've found all the info here very informative. Thanks for all you do.

EDIT:
Here is the current code with the syntax error

```
<?php
include('codelibrary/inc/variables.php');
include("session.php");
$obj= new database_class();

$query = $obj->getAnyTableAllData($obj->getTable("var_customer")," and email != '' order by email ");
$filename = 'customer_email.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');


# let's get keys into an order that you like
$fields = array('email','first_name','business','phone_no','shipping_address');

foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
// put the fields for this row into an array
foreach ($fields as $field) { 
    $data[] = $v[$field];
}
fputcsv($fp, $data);
unset($data);
}

 fclose($fp);

if(is_file($filename))
{
$size=filesize("$filename");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($filename);

 exit;
 }
 else
  {
        echo "Invalid file!";
         }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSVs, instead of `fwrite`, you can use `fputcsv`, you just pass it an array of columns to insert in the row.

`$array = array('column one contents', 'column two contents');
fputcsv($fp, $array);`

Comment: Any chance you can show me where to put this in the existing code?

Comment: Aric Watson's answer gives you the idea, but `fputcsv` takes a single row only, so instead of taking `$data` and adding it to  `$lines`, just write it to the file.

Comment: Would I just be removing this line? 
$lines[] = $data; // add the row of data to $lines

Sorry for the questions. First time delving this deep into php into csv.

Comment: Yes, just replace that line with `fputcsv($fp, $data)`

Comment: and then remove `fputcsv($fp, $lines);` a few lines below that

Comment: Almost there I think. I got this error. 

arse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET on line 20

Comment: Need a semicolon `fputcsv($fp, $data);`.  Pretty much all `unexpected x` errors are either a missing semicolon or mismatched braces/parentheses

Comment: I'd have to see the code to figure out why.  If you edit your question with the updated code I can take a look.

Comment: Just updated it with the code giving the error below the original code.

Comment: Hm, it shouldn't still be giving you that error. Everything looks fine to me.  I don't get an error at that line when I run it myself

Comment: When I refresh the page with the error it downloads the csv file with everything correctly

Comment: Oh, that's normal.  When you force download (which you're doing here, that's what the `header()` calls are doing), it doesn't display anything, so whatever was on the page last time you loaded it stays there.  So even though the error is still there, that's just because no additional content was sent to the browser, not because it's encountering the error again.  If you were to close the page and try it in a new window it won't show anymore.

Comment: There we go! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into fputcsv.

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code was looping through all the data, printing out the `email`. Then looping again and printing out the `first_name`... I haven't tested it, but this uses fputcsv to write the file - I changed only those parts of the code.

```
<?php
include('codelibrary/inc/variables.php');
include("session.php");
$obj= new database_class();

    $query = $obj->getAnyTableAllData($obj->getTable("var_customer")," and email != '' order by email ");
$filename = 'customer_email.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');


# let's get keys into an order that you like
$fields = array('email','first_name','business','phone_no','shipping_address');

foreach ($query as $k=>$v) {
    // put the fields for this row into an array
    foreach ($fields as $field) { 
        $data[] = $v[$field];
    }
    $lines[] = $data; // add the row of data to $lines
    unset($data);
}

fputcsv($fp, $lines);

fclose($fp);

if(is_file($filename))
{
    $size=filesize("$filename");
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($filename);

     exit;
     }
 else
      {
            echo "Invalid file!";
             }
?>
```

Comment: No data pulls with this.